# .net letting window know of unhandeled exception

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, exception

I am wondering if there is anyway to let your window (wpf) know of an unhandeled exception before the dispatcher kicks in?

Reasons for this:
- I have a global unhandled code at application.xaml.vb. this opens a special window that contains StackTrace information.
- At the window level, i have a user control that I would like to change properties based on messages. now i normally do this by putting try/catch, but by doing this, i will be handeling the exception, and thus the special msgbox will never show.

is there any way to keep the exception unhandled and letting the window know of the problem before the dispatcher kicks in? if so, how?

APPLICATION - Start
WINDOW - Open
CODE THAT THROWS EXCEPTION()
          <------i need something here, that runs code while keeping the code as unhandeled.
UNHANDELED_EXCEPTION() on APPLICATION

Comment: Just throw the exception back after catching it.

Comment: tried that, but the application consideres it caught. basically if it enteres the catch, its caught (handled). is there anyway to put ex.handled = false?

Comment: I've never heard of a caught state for exceptions. Maybe if you show us a bit of code it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I think that you want to catch unhandled `Exception`s so that you can perform some work before the application closes. If that is correct, then you can try handling the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void MainWindow_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
    Error error = new Error(exception, mainViewModel.StateManager.CurrentUser);
    // log error
    mainViewModel.AddError(error); 
}
```

Comment: if by mainwindow_unhandledexception() you mean application event, then yes, this is already done. My problem is at the window level, i want to "hear" unhandeled exceptions and do some small bit of ui updates, and then, let the application event run its course.

Comment: An unhandled `Exception` cannot be handled at a later stage. It is an `Exception` that *will* close your application. These `Exception`s will be caught in this handler and after logging the error, the application will close.